# Unable to convert model from Keras to Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I get the following binary classification Keras model, which trains not well, but trains:

```
def vgg_stack(self):
    def func(x):
        x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
        x = layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

        x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
        x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)

        x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
        x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)

        x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
        x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)

        x = layers.Flatten()(x)
        x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
        x = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
        x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

        return x

    return func

def implement(self):
    self.inputs = layers.Input((self.input_width, self.input_height, self.input_depth))
    self.outputs = self.vgg_stack()(self.inputs)

    self.opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=self.learning_rate)
    self.model = models.Model(inputs=self.inputs, outputs=self.outputs)
    self.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=self.opt)

def fit_predict(self):
    ...
    self.model.fit(data_train, actuals_train, batch_size=self.batch_size, epochs=10, verbose=1,
                   validation_data=[data_validation, actuals_validation], callbacks=[self])
```

it's predictions look like following

```
[[ 0.58952832]
 [ 0.89163774]
 [ 0.99083483]
 ..., 
 [ 0.52727282]
 [ 0.72056866]
 [ 0.99504411]]
```

I.e. it's something.

I tried to convert the model to pure tensroflow and got

```
def conv2drelu(self, x, filters, kernel_size, padding='VALID'):

    input_depth = int(x.get_shape()[-1])

    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([kernel_size[0], kernel_size[0], input_depth, filters],
                                              dtype=tf.float32, stddev=self.init_stddev))

    self.var_list.append(weights)

    biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[filters], dtype=tf.float32))

    self.var_list.append(biases)

    y = tf.nn.conv2d(x, weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding=padding)

    y = tf.nn.bias_add(y, biases)

    y = tf.nn.relu(y)

    return y

def maxpooling(self, x, pool_size, strides, padding='VALID'):

    y = tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, pool_size[0], pool_size[1], 1], strides=[1, strides[0], strides[1], 1],
                       padding=padding)

    return y

def flatten(self, x):

    shape = int(np.prod(x.get_shape()[1:]))

    y = tf.reshape(x, [-1, shape])

    return y

def dense(self, x, units, activation):

    shape = int(x.get_shape()[1])

    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([shape, units], dtype=tf.float32, stddev=self.init_stddev))

    self.var_list.append(weights)

    biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[units], dtype=tf.float32))

    self.var_list.append(biases)

    y = tf.matmul(x, weights)

    y = tf.nn.bias_add(y, biases)

    if activation == 'relu':

        y = tf.nn.relu(y)

    elif activation == 'sigmoid':

        y = tf.nn.sigmoid(y)

    return y

def vgg_stack(self, x):

    x = self.conv2drelu(x, 64, (3, 3))
    x = self.maxpooling(x, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2))

    x = self.conv2drelu(x, 128, (3, 3))
    x = self.maxpooling(x, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2))

    x = self.conv2drelu(x, 128, (3, 3))
    x = self.maxpooling(x, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2))

    x = self.conv2drelu(x, 64, (3, 3))
    x = self.maxpooling(x, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2))

    x = self.flatten(x)

    x = self.dense(x, 512, activation='relu')
    x = self.dense(x, 256, activation='relu')
    x = self.dense(x, 1, activation='sigmoid')

    return x

def implement(self):

    self.var_list = []

    self.input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, self.width, self.height, self.depth))

    self.prediction = self.vgg_stack(self.input_data)

    self.actual = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))

    self.log_loss = tf.losses.log_loss(self.actual, self.prediction)

    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)

    # self.step = opt.minimize(self.mean_squared_error, var_list=self.var_list)
    self.step = opt.minimize(self.log_loss, var_list=self.var_list)
```

i.e. I tries to write functions equivalent to each Keras layer and then combine them into the same structure.

I used all the same numbers. Unfortunately, network provides something degraded:

```
[[ 0.46732453]
 [ 0.46732453]
 [ 0.46732453]
 ..., 
 [ 0.46732453]
 [ 0.46732453]
 [ 0.46732453]]
```

I.e. the same values for all samples.

What can be the reason of this?

Comment: Do you feed same input data in both cases?

Comment: Yes, I have only one function to retreive data and use it. I also tried to disable shuffling in `Keras`, but it still does some train. Looks like I suffer from symmetry unbroken? Don't you see errors in my layer implementations also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion was correct. I wrote unittests for convolution layers from Keras and Tensorflow and found they produce numerically identical results.

Additionally, I replaced optimization goal from just log-loss to [`sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) but this didn't helped alone.

The problem was with too small `stdev` of initialization values.

I was thinking it is enough to have it very small to break symmetry, and was setting it to `1e-8` or `1e-5`, but this was wrong: such small values were nearly identical to zeros and after several layers network was starting to produce identical results for all samples.

After I changed `stdev` to `1e-1`, then netwrok started to perfor as in `Keras`.